# How to get rid of grey line at bottom of Bootstrap panel heading?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

### Problem

I have these panels, which I have successfully changed the colors of:
[image]

But when I expand the panels, there is a thin grey border at the bottom of each panel header:

[image]
[image]

How can I get rid of that sliver of grey?

### My Code

*CSS*

```
.panel-wrong{
    border-color: #FED0D3;
}
.panel-wrong > .panel-heading{
    background: #FED0D3;
    color: #F53240;
    border-color: #FED0D3;
}

.panel-right{
    border-color: #E5FFFB;
}

.panel-right > .panel-heading{
    background: #E5FFFB;
    color: #02C8A7;
    border-color: #E5FFFB;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default panel-wrong">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                            </h4> </div>
                        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default panel-wrong">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Collapsible Group 2</a>
      </h4> </div>
                        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">panel body 2</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default panel-right">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
        Collapsible Group 3</a>
      </h4> </div>
                        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">panel body 3</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/wzepw41a/12/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.panel-group .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border: none;
}
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wzepw41a/14/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.panel-group .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .list-group, .panel-group .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
border-top: medium none;
}
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score -1):

The particular property that you are hunting for is the `border-top-color` property of the `.panel-body` selector. By changing it's value to `transparent` you should remove that, thus:

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body {
    border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.